# Quick Rest API with Python for mocking responses

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, api

I am testing a C# application that make requests to another Rest API and I want to mock the server. I known basic python and I was wondering if I can write a simple API Rest server without be involved with large frameworks like Django. It would be a simple server where I receive a json through request body and I have to return another json (with the logic of the return inside, like a view).

Best regards!

Something simple like this:

```
@path(/api/v1/somepath, GET)
def my_function(request):
    json_input = request.body.json()

    # My logic here
    response.status = 200
    response.body = {'some_field': 'something'}
    return response
```

Comment: @nice you can also have a look at JSON Server : https://github.com/typicode/json-server which comes in very handy for mocking APIs. Provides a complete set of HTTP verbs, including GET, POST, PUT without a single line of code!

Comment: @nico Also look at the Flask : http://flask.pocoo.org/. Its python only, dead simple to use and get started!

Comment: Why a server? Why not just mock the request library itself and avoid network connectivity entirely?

Comment: @MartijnPieters would that require to mock inside the C# program?

Comment: Yes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650441.aspx

Comment: Well that is an approach I can not handle, because this is for Blackbox testing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you really don't want to use any external frameworks/ libraries, you can create a simple class which extends `BaseHTTPRequestHandler`, something like this :

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import json

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.data_string = self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length']))

        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

        data = json.loads(self.data_string)
        # your processing
        outJson = {"success": True}
        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(outJson))

    def do_HEAD(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("HEAD")

    def do_POST(self):
        self._set_headers()
        self.wfile.write("POST")
```

and then start the server locally at the port of your choice(80 by default) simply like this:

```
def run(port=80):
    httpd = HTTPServer(('', port), S)
    print 'Starting httpd...'
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv
    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

and if you need to manage lots of routes easily, you can use [`klein`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/klein/0.2.3) or [`Flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org) microframeworks (or even [`bottle`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html)) to make it easier and simpler for you, a simple minimal usage example for using `klein` would look something like this:

```
import json
from klein import Klein

class ItemStore(object):
    app = Klein()

    def __init__(self):
        self._items = {}

    @app.route('/')
    def items(self, request):
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return json.dumps(self._items)

    @app.route('/<string:name>', methods=['PUT'])
    def save_item(self, request, name):
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        body = json.loads(request.content.read())
        self._items[name] = body
        return json.dumps({'success': True})

    @app.route('/<string:name>', methods=['GET'])
    def get_item(self, request, name):
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return json.dumps(self._items.get(name))
```

and then run the server like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    store = ItemStore()
    store.app.run('localhost', 8080)
```

Also, if you want to use the mock apis remotely and not just locally, you can use tunneling tools like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com). It's pretty simple and easy to use.

Comment: Yeah but how do you bind /api/v1/somepath with that GET for instance? BTW content type should not be json?

Comment: It looks great, did not know about klein, May also set the status code in the response?

Comment: @Nico yes! `request.setResponseCode(200)` that's it, by default it sends `200`

Comment: Great Ashish, ASAIC I am going to test this!

Comment: @Nico also, you might find [this](http://klein.readthedocs.io/) useful, it's the detailed documentation for klein.

Comment: What do I have to install to get "BaseHTTPServer"? `pip install <what package>`

Comment: nothing, it's python [builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) @Nico

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'BaseHTTPServer'` :( . I am on python3 but I don't think that is a problem

Comment: @Nico yes it is! for python 3 use : `http.server` instead, as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html) , also why don't you try `klein` or `flask`, should be better in your case.

Comment: Nice, now I am able to run the server but I am doing something worng, I am not getting the PATH that I have already defined on my server. For example: `@app.route('/api/v1/saraza', methods=['GET'])
    def saraza(self, request, name):
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        return json.dumps({"saraza":"saraza"})` When I go to the browser with that path, that returns 404 :(

Comment: Don't worry, I was able to do it, you won't believe what I did.

Comment: great! what was it btw?

Comment: Did not the save the change, LOL.